# How to use scalar pandas_udf in pyspark on array type columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm trying to implement scalar pandas_udf in spark, but getting errors while executing the specific operation. Below are details about structure of columns and udf which I've written:

```
dataframe schema for array type column:

list_col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, flatten, pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import Row


@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def truncate_data_udf(list_type_col, output_list_length):     
    sortedList=pd.Series(list_type_col).tolist()    
    un_list=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sortedList))
    trunc_size=int(output_list_length)   
    if len(un_list)>trunc_size:
        un_list=un_list[:trunc_size]
        un_list.insert(0, 'truncated')

    return pd.Series(un_list)

df = df.withColumn("list_col", truncate_data_udf(flatten(F.col("list_col1")), lit(10)))

Expected result is truncated list having elements equal to 10.
```

So in what format or data-type inputs are being passed to pandas_udf. If I want to convert input column data to list, then how I can do that. And while returning the data set, how I can return the result in form of list.

```
The result column should have schema like:
list_col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I've also wrote a regular udf like below, which is working as expected. But I want to identify the difference in terms of performs between regular and pandas_udf. I believe pandas_udf are much faster than normal udf.

```
Normal udf:

def truncate_data(list_type_col, output_list_length): 
    l= list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_type_col))
    if l is not None and len(l) > output_list_length:
        l = l[:output_list_length]        
        l.insert(0, 'truncated')    
    return(l)

truncate_data_udf= udf(lambda row: truncate_data(row, output_list_length), ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn("list_col", truncate_data_udf(flatten(F.col("list_col1"))))
```

Comment: Can you post the error with the trace?

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' : This is error I'm getting while using the mentioned pandas udf.

Comment: Both The input to and output from a pandas_udf should be a pandas series, your flatten call is sending in a numpy array instead